# Responsive CSS- swap element positions on alternate rows

Tags: css, css-grid, responsive

I'm trying to arrange image/description paired items in a grid layout so that they appear reversed on alternate rows regardless of the numbers of items in a row (when the page is resized).

Something like this.

[image: Grid 2x3]

**--then after shrinking the broswer window--**

[image: Grid 3x2]

I have `.list{ grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr)); }` for the basic layout.
And I've tried using `.list > :nth-child(2n) { grid-column-start: 2; }` to switch positions, but it just becomes a mess. And now I'm chasing my tail.

Is it possible to do this with pure CSS?

Comment: If you know the widths when the layout changes you should be able to set different styles using media queries and `nth-child` selectors to target the elements of each row for each width range

Comment: This is the way I've gone and it seems to be working so far. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using CSS frameworks, Bootstrap has exactly what you are looking for. [Take a look here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#responsive-classes)